# Validate a group within a group with Jquery validation

Tags: jquery, validation

I know this code is awful, but it works except for one part:

I already have the 2 checkboxes that appear in each group when you select "yes" to become required if you check any of the 3 checkboxes (newsletter, newsletter2 or newsletter3) as shown in Figure 1 here:

[image: Figure 1]

But when one selects "yes" in the "More?" dropdown menu in the first place, I'd the 3 choices (newsletter, newsletter2 & newsletter3) below it to become required (you have to pick at least one choice / minlength: 1) as shown in Figure 2 here:

[image: Figure 2]

Everything works and submits, but I'm stuck at this part.  In a nutshell, I want the the 3 choices you first see (before clicking on them) to have you require to click at least one of the 3 before it validates.

Here the code that works so far:

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$.validator.setDefaults({
});

$().ready(function() {

    $("#commentForm").validate({

        rules: {

            'entry.7.group': {
                required: "#newsletter:checked",
                minlength: 1
                                            },
            'entry.77.group': {
                required: "#newsletter2:checked",
                minlength: 1
                            },
            'entry.777.group': {
                required: "#newsletter3:checked",
                minlength: 1
                            }
        }
    }); 
    });
</script>

<script language="JavaScript">
  function showhidefield1()
  {
    if (document.mainform.more.value == 'yes')
    {
      document.getElementById("hideablearea1").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("newsletter.group").find("input").val("").addClass("required");

    }
    else
    {
      document.getElementById("hideablearea1").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("newsletter.group").find("input").val("").removeClass("required");

    }
  }
</script>


<script language="JavaScript">
  function showhidefield2()
  {
    if (document.mainform.newsletter.checked)
    {
      document.getElementById("hideablearea2").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("group_7_1").find("input").val("").addClass("required");
      document.getElementById("group_7_2").find("input").val("").addClass("required");
    }
    else
    {
      document.getElementById("hideablearea2").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("group_7_1").find("input").val("").removeClass("required");
      document.getElementById("group_7_2").find("input").val("").removeClass("required");
    }
  }
</script>

<script language="JavaScript">
  function showhidefield3()
  {
    if (document.mainform.newsletter2.checked)
    {
      document.getElementById("hideablearea3").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("group_77_1").find("input").val("").addClass("required");
      document.getElementById("group_77_2").find("input").val("").addClass("required");
    }
    else
    {
      document.getElementById("hideablearea3").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("group_77_1").find("input").val("").removeClass("required");
      document.getElementById("group_77_2").find("input").val("").removeClass("required");
    }
  }
</script>

<script language="JavaScript">
  function showhidefield4()
  {
    if (document.mainform.newsletter3.checked)
    {
      document.getElementById("hideablearea4").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("group_777_1").find("input").val("").addClass("required");
      document.getElementById("group_777_2").find("input").val("").addClass("required");
    }
    else
    {
      document.getElementById("hideablearea4").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("group_777_1").find("input").val("").removeClass("required");
      document.getElementById("group_777_2").find("input").val("").removeClass("required");
    }
  }
</script>


<style type="text/css">
label.error {
color: #ff0600; list-style-position: outside;
clear: left;
display: inline;
float:right;
height:10px;}
}
</style>

</head>
```

And then there's this in the body:

```
      <select name="newsletter4" class="required" id="more" onchange="showhidefield1()">
      <option value="">More?</option><option value="yes">Yes</option><option value="no">No</option></select>
  <div id='hideablearea1' style='display:none'>
<br><br>

            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="newsletter" name="newsletter.group" onclick="showhidefield2()"/>Newsletter
            <div id='hideablearea2' style='display:none'>
            <input type="checkbox" id="group_7_1" value="Choice 1" name="entry.7.group" />Choice 1
            <input type="checkbox" id="group_7_2" value="Choice 2" name="entry.7.group" />Choice 2

             <br><br></div>
<br><br>

             <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="newsletter2" name="newsletter.group" onclick="showhidefield3()"/>Newsletter2
             <div id='hideablearea3' style='display:none'>

            <input type="checkbox" id="group_77_1" value="Choice 1" name="entry.77.group" />Choice 1  
            <input type="checkbox" id="group_77_2" value="Choice 2" name="entry.77.group" />Choice 2
           </div>
<br><br>           
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="newsletter3" name="newsletter.group" onclick="showhidefield4()"/>Newsletter3
            <div id='hideablearea4' style='display:none'>

            <input type="checkbox" id="group_777_1" value="Choice 1" name="entry.777.group" />Choice 1
            <input type="checkbox" id="group_777_2" value="Choice 2" name="entry.777.group" />Choice 2   

      </div>
      </div>

            <p></p>
    <input type="hidden" name="pageNumber" value="0"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="backupCache" value=""> 


  <div class="ss-item ss-navigate"><div class="ss-form-entry"> 
  <p>
    <input name="pageNumber" type="hidden" value="0" />
    <input name="backupCache" type="hidden" />
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit Form"/>
```

Comment: Is there anyone who knows what I can do to solve this? If it's too complicated or if my code is too shabby to figure out, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to customize your own flavor of the "required" rule. Check this out:
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/required#dependency-expression

It should lead you down the right path.

Comment: Thank you.  I looked at that earlier, but I’m not sure how I'd apply that to change my code above and make it work.  I figure it must be something different with this code "required: "#more:checked"" where instead of "checked" it should somehow know yes means "checked".  I also figure I need to have my group organized in a way that it all can validate.  I have no idea how to do this, hopefully someone here knows how I can change my code to make it work.